# Spring data repository MongoDB

Tags: spring-data

I user Spring Data and will search entries by firstname, surname, email or username. Do I have to set the parameters four times or is it possible to only set the parameter once?
Thanks!

```
userRepository.findUsersByFirstnameOrSurnameOrEmailOrUsername("Mustermann", "Mustermann",
        "Mustermann", "Mustermann");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the query to be automatically generated from the method name, then yes, you would have to pass 4 parameters and if all of them can have the same value in some cases, that same value will have to be passed 4 times.

If however you are willing to trade-off ease of passing parameters against automatic query generation, you can use the `@Query` annotation to generate your own query.  This annotation will take any valid MongoDB query so for your case, the MongoDB query will be:

```
> db.user.find({ $or : [{"firstName" : "Mustermann"}, {"surname" : "Mustermann"}, {"email" : "Mustermann"}, {"userName" : "Mustermann"}] });
```

You can therefore code the query as:

```
@Query("$or : [{'firstName' : ?1}, {'surname' : ?1}, {'email' : ?1}, {'userName' : ?1}]")
List<User> findUsersByFirstnameOrSurnameOrEmailOrUsername(String keyword);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for help! one small correction - index starts with 0. Thanks

Comment: I would have one mor question concerning this query. I would like to have a "like" statement:  **@Query("{$or : [{'firstname' : ?0}, {'surname' : ?0}, {'email' : ?0}, {'username' : ?0} ] }")**  - so that e.g. firstname should not be exactly the name but also can be a fragment of the firstname

Comment: MongoDB supports something called [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text).  For fields on which you would like to perform `LIKE` queries, you would apply the [`@TextIndexed`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.full-text) annotation in the entity class, as: `@TextIndexed private String firstName;` and so on.  Then, you would simply issue the MongoDB query `@Query("$text : { $search : ?0 } }")`.  MongoDB will then perform a full-text search on all fields annotated with `@TextIndexed`.